# What is the best way to implement an interface as shown in pictures below?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I know of the expandable list view but it is vertical while I want to implement an interface as shown in the picture. Would I need to create four activities, each for Player, Library, Disable explicit content and Find us?

[image: The settings page]
This is the second interface which comes up when you press on Player[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a series of `PreferenceScreens` with custom styling. See [the documentation section on Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) for how to set this up and split your preferences across screens.

For the right cheverons you could use the [widgetLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference#attr_android:widgetLayout) attribute to set a custom layout that has the cheveron. Or the [layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference#attr_android:layout) attribute which give you even more control but is more advanced / complicated.

Comment: This is a better solution. I checked it out and fits what I am looking for. However, do you know how we could bring that little arrow for four settings? There are two icons one at left and one at right for these four items

Comment: Updated answer.